# Why is the result of this array 9 and not the contents of the array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Why does:

```
code3_x = []
level = 7

(level + 2).times do |i|
# This is more what I want:
# code3_x[i] << i
# This works to demonstrate:
  code3_x << i
end
```

return:

```
=> 9
```

Why not?

```
=> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I create an array as `code3_x` & I have a value `x` *(replace the second `i` with a conditionally chosen number, just reusing `i` in the example as a place holder)* I want to insert `x` at a particular index in code3_x.

*note:*

I'm trying to translate the following javascript to ruby
*this is just a snip of a larger function*

```
if ... conditions ...{
  code3_x[i] =2;
  mod_x -= h_pow;
}else...
```

**Update:**
*here is a link to a gist of the entire javascript function I am trying to re-implement in ruby.*
https://gist.github.com/therocketforever/d1dca656f4579bc5baf3

Comment: The code example you have doesn’t even run successfully…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you have a typo in that code. `<<` is not defined on `code3_x[i]` (which is `nil`).
The version with `code3_x[i] = i` returns `9` because the return value of `#times` is the object you're sending the message to (in this case `(level + 2)`). `code3_x` will still be set:

```
(level + 2).times do |i|
  code3_x[i] = i
end # => 9
code3_x # => [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

If you need the return value, you could for example use `#map` with a range

```
(0..9).map{ |i| i * i } # => [0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: yup your right.... kinda, << is what I had originally. it should be pointing at code3_x not [i]. The thing is need the return value, just not yet.... as in I will do this a few more times.

Answer (score 0):

because you're doing a bit-shift ;) try

```
code3_x[i] = i
```